# Shift letter position in a word

Tags: bash, text-processing, tr

I want a command/function, preferably bash, that takes a word/string and a number and shifts the letter positions in the word by that number, rotating the overflow back to the beginning.

e.g. with input `stack` and `2` the output would be `cksta`

I have thought about using `tr` but I couldn't quite figure out how to make it general so as to work with any word, and not just translating specific letters from a target word.

Comment: There is no way to do this with `tr` in the general case.  If your string is guaranteed to not contain the characters which are to be rotated anywhere except in the part which is to be rotated, you can remove them with `tr`, but that is a rather tortured argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bash`'s built-in string manipulation:

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$1
shift=$2

length=${#string}
echo ${string:$length-$shift:$shift}${string:0:$length-$shift}
```

Example:

```
$ ./script stack 1
kstac
$ ./script stack 2
cksta
$ ./script stack 3
ackst
$ ./script stack 4
tacks
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! as a note to anyone else reading this you can shift the other way, by adding the length of the string to the shift variable.

Comment: I didn't understand: length=${#string} Then I found a worth reading here:
String Lenght. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

Answer (score 2):

Another common approach is to "double" the string, which simplifies the substringery:

```
str=stack
len=${#str}
n=2
strstr=$str$str
echo ${strstr:$len-$n:$len}   # -> cksta
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter is the usage of negative values, to count from right:

```
string=$1
shift=$2
length=${#string}
echo ${string: -shift}${string:0:length-shift}
```

since :- has an own meaning, you have to put a blank before it.